# Newbie with Rails devise and view of the user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise, view

I'm looking into RoR some way to: login into the system with DEVISE, (it's working), but i'm needing something than keeps always the view of this logged user, and avoid than this user looks another views.

http://xx.xx.xx.xx:3000/user/1

And this user cannot look the content of:

http://xx.xx.xx.xx:3000/user/2.

Please, sorry if this is a silly question, but, i was looking 2 days and i don't know how i can name this feature.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are gems available for this Authorization. I prefer can can which is one of the best Authorization gems available

Here is the gem=> https://github.com/ryanb/cancan

And here is the rails cast tutorial using it=> http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan

**EDIT:** If you want to manually implement this then you just need to make a method with following logic

```
def check_authorization
  # Assuming user ID is coming in params[:id]
   if current_user.id == params[:id]
      return
   else
      # render or redirect to some page with access denied message
   end
end
```

And call this method just before any action in which you want to check for authorization.

Comment: Excelent help. I look the video of the use and seems simplier and cleaner than devise. I'm have a doubt with the manually implement than you indicated. This should be in the ApplicationController? or where you recommends?  Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: If you are planning to use this method in more than one controller then it should reside in application controller so it would be available for use in all controller...

other wise if you are using it in only single controller then write it in that controller but make it private method.

Comment: Thanks! i'm new here, so i cant give you points to your help yet.